# Consolidating two Macros into One

Tags: vba, excel

I have two similar macros I've written, and for efficiency's sake I'd like to consolidate them into one. The first macro adds 4 blank rows on another tab underneath a specific row, where column C matches certain criteria. The second macro copies 4 rows of data from an existing tab over to the new tab, and pastes that data into the 4 newly created blank rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Conceptual screenshots attached: 
Screenshot 1: [Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Van.png)
Screenshot 2: [MACRO 1 inserts 4 rows if criteria in column C is met (in this case value = "Part A"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpdM2.png)
Screenshot 3: [MACRO 2 pulls in row data from another sheet and pastes it into the new blank rows on this sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dNlU.png)

FIRST MACRO:

```
Sub RowAdder_01()

Dim Col As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim PN_01 As Range
Set PN_01 = Range("M17")

    Col = "C"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With Worksheets("NEW SHEET")
For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
If .Cells(R, Col) = PN_01 Then
.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

SECOND MACRO:

```
Sub PasteRowData_01()

Dim Col As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim PN_01 As Range
Set PN_01 = Range("M17")

    Col = "C"
    Drop = "A"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("OLD SHEET").Rows("54:57").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy

    With Worksheets("NEW SHEET")
For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
If .Cells(R, Col) = PN_01 Then
   Sheets(NEW SHEET).Select
    .Cells(R + 1, Drop).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial

End If
Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be better to attach a picture for your understanding.

Comment: What happens when you put them both in the same macro?

Comment: Why do you believe it is more efficient to include both sets of code into a single macro, rather than just invoking both macros - one after the other?

Comment: Dy.Lee and Heath, thank you both for your responses. Screenshots are now linked for additional reference. My goal is to (1) insert the new row and (2) populate them with data from another tab in one macro/step. I tried adding the lower portion of MACRO 2, beginning with the line "Sheets("OLD Sheet)" after the last ".Cells(R + 1, Col)" line, and it says I have a "For" error.

Comment: YowE3K, thanks for your comment. The macros above reference one specific cell in a table that contains a longer list of "parts." In the screenshots above, I'm only inserting rows where the value in column C = "Part A." I might end up having 20 different parts in this table, and I would like for the user to have individual macros for each part (they may not need to insert rows for each part, only a select few). Right now, I would have to create 40 macro buttons, one to insert the rows, one to populate data in the new rows.

Comment: I would prefer to only have one that does both functions, bringing the total buttons to 20. Even if I create one macro that runs both of the macros from my initial post in sequence, I would still have to have to code 40 modules, plus another 20 to run the two in sequence.

Comment: Once the first macro completes the last [.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown] action, I would like it to continue onward with [Sheets("OLD SHEET").Rows("54:57").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy] within the second macro.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddAndPaste()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim PN_01 As Variant
    Dim Last As Long                        ' column or row
    Dim R As Long

    ' copy from source
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Old Sheet")
    With Ws
        With .UsedRange
            Last = .Columns.Count + .Column - 1
        End With
        Arr = Range(.Cells(54, 1), .Cells(57, Last)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' paste to destination
    Set Ws = Worksheets("New Sheet")
    With Ws
        PN_01 = .Cells(7, "M").Value
        Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        For R = Last To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(R, "C").Value = PN_01 Then
                With .Cells(R, "A")
                    .Resize(4, 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    .Offset(-4).Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
                End With
                Exit For           ' don't exit if you need to continue looping
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Variatus. Thanks so much for your help! I gave the code above a run (first tweaked the row from 7 to 17 - to reference cell M17 on the old sheet), and it appears to paste the 4 new rows directly underneath my header row on the new sheet (originally row 5) as hard values. All of the rows on the new sheet that contain the value referenced by M17 are for some reason not recognized - no new rows or data is inserted underneath. Thank you again.

Comment: That's because I don't really know what your code is supposed to do. Pls fill me in. My code looks for the value of 'New Sheet'!M17 (yes, I tested with 7) in 'New Sheet'!C:C. Apparently it finds that value in your header and inserts the new rows there. There seem to be several errors in this scenario. Is the Value from 'Old Sheet'!M17 instead? And is it a cell value at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by inserting a line. We recommend using an array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, newWs As Worksheet, Temp As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vSp, vR()
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, n As Long, k As Integer, cnt As Integer
    Dim PN_01 As Range


    Set newWs = Sheets("New Sheet")
    Set oldWs = Sheets("OLD SHEET")
    Set Temp = Sheets.Add
    oldWs.Range("a54:d57").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Temp.Range("a1")
    vSp = Temp.UsedRange
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Temp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    With newWs
        vDB = .Range("a1", "d" & .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Set PN_01 = .Range("M17")
    End With
    cnt = UBound(vSp, 1)
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)

    For i = 1 To r
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
        For j = 1 To 4
            vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        If vDB(i, 3) = PN_01 Then
            For k = 1 To cnt
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
                For j = 1 To 4
                    vR(j, n) = vSp(k, j)
                Next j
            Next k
        End If
    Next i
    newWs.Range("a1").Resize(n, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    newWs.Activate
End Sub
```